# flask_oauthlib invalid response from discord

Tags: python, flask, discord, flask-oauthlib

I am currently writing a discord dashboard for my discord bot and using flask oauth library to deal with the oauth from discord.

This is the code that is handling the oauth.

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return discord_oauth.authorize(callback=url_for('authorized', _external=True))

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('discord_token', None)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/authorized')
def authorized():
    resp = discord_oauth.authorized_response()
    print("resp data" + resp.data)
    print("resp status" + resp.status)
    print("resp content" + resp.content)
    if resp is None or isinstance(resp, Exception):
        return 'Access denied: reason=' + request.args['error'] + '&error_description=' + request.args['error_description']
    
    session['discord_token'] = (resp['access_token'], '')
    return redirect(url_for('select_guild'))
```

When i click authorize and head to the redirect uri specified in the code and in the discord oauth page this error appears.

```
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 548-765-053
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jun/2023 20:57:32] "GET /authorized?code=MMwkjYncCyrM9BDIozg0CcLCcNFfya HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2213, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2193, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bob\Documents\JellyFishBot\main.py", line 46, in authorized
    resp = discord_oauth.authorized_response()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask_oauthlib\client.py", line 708, in authorized_response
    data = self.handle_oauth2_response(args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask_oauthlib\client.py", line 691, in handle_oauth2_response
    raise OAuthException(
flask_oauthlib.client.OAuthException: Invalid response from discord
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jun/2023 20:57:33] "GET /authorized?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jun/2023 20:57:33] "GET /authorized?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Jun/2023 20:57:33] "GET /authorized?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

As you can see with the print statements in authorized I have tried to rule out the issue but when trying to print them out they don't print.